# COUNTIFS with many conditions from a dropdown list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now I have a table that I created with COUNTIFS that checks for country names (chosen from a dropdown list located on cell B3) and other values.

So for example I have something like this

```
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,">=3",MySheet!C:C,B3)
```

So at the moment I can choose places like Canada, England, United States, etc. (Basically, all countries in the world)

What I want to do is add an option called "all" where it shows the data for all countries. I was wondering how I can do that in the COUNTIFS without having to do MySheet!C:C,"Canada",MySheet!C:C,"England", and like that for every single country in the world.

Comment: You can use a `IF()` condition like `=IF(B3="All",COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,">=3"),COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,">=3",MySheet!C:C,B3))`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean: `=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,">=3",MySheet!C:C,"<>")`

Comment: Will that just ask for "no condition" when it comes to choosing a country?

Comment: @P.b What will happen if op select a country like `England` to `B3` cell?

Comment: @Harun, I simply provided the solution for retrieving all countries, not how it's selected. Your version of the answer covers that (and leaving out the `"<>"` part results in the same outcome, so it's a better solution anyway). I suggest you to post it as answer rather than comment.